# DetachedCriteria throws unknown entity null

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two mapped tables as follows (in the database, the recipient_id is a foreign key to the player table):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="recipient_recipient_group")
public class RecipientRecipientGroup {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="recipient_group_id")
    private String recipientGroupId;

    @Column(name="recipient_id")
    private int recipientId;

    //GET, SET
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "player")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Player {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "ps_id")
    private String psId;

    //GET, SET and some other stuff not relating to the RecipientRecipientGroup entity

}
```

I need to write the criteria-subquery. I tryied the following subquery:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Player.class);
if(groupId != null){
    DetachedCriteria ownerCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(RecipientRecipientGroup.class, "group");
    ownerCriteria.setProjection(Property.forName("group.recipient_id"));
    ownerCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("group.recipient_group_id", groupId));
    criteria.add(Property.forName("id").in(ownerCriteria));
}
```

I got the exception:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: null
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:548)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getPropertyMapping(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:518)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getType(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:477)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getTypeUsingProjection(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:459)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getTypedValue(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:509)
    org.hibernate.criterion.SimpleExpression.getTypedValues(SimpleExpression.java:71)
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: The Criteria API, just as HQL, NEVER uses table and column names. ALWAYS entity names and field/property names. Also, Why don't you use associations between entities? Why do you have a String field mapped to a foreign key to an integer column?

Comment: @JBNizet It was just a typo. Of course, I have integer foreign key.

Comment: @JBNizet Is it even possible to write such a query with a subquery?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But you need to respect the above rules.

Comment: @JB Nizet You help me out, thank you. But I couldn't get why we have to specify an alias if we're writing subqueries.

Comment: Your sample is to much short. Hibernate is good server, but evil lord. We need to know how SQL looks like. Sub-query can be used in select part of SQL, or in where clause and there can be used many ways - as equality, in clause, exists clause etc.